# MySQLconnection in entity framework 4

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I'm trying to use a MySQLdatabase with Entity Framework 4

I've installed the connector from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/ but still when i try to add the conection there's no option for MySQL

Am i missing something?

Comment: have you rebooted your system since installing the connector? At the very least restart Visual Studio IDE.

Comment: huh... I've restarted visual studio, will try restarting the system now...

Comment: Also, you may want to try installing the connector after closing ALL .NET apps that may be running, including VS201x. Sometimes when they are running during install it can't get proper permissions and causes a conflict with sharing like resources.

Comment: @AmitApollo that's not it. Just uninstalled and installed again with nothing but the installer open and rebooted after it but the option is still not available. Might it be some configuration i'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i've been searching arround and found out why this is happening, so for anyone who is trying to use MySql connector with an Express version you should know that Visual Studio Express DOES NOT support MySQL .NET Connector as extension.